# Does MySQL store somehow the last querie(s)?

Tags: mysql, performance

While working with MySQL and some really "performance greedy queries" I noticed, that if I run such a greedy query it could take 2 or 3 minutes to be computed. But if I retry the query immediately after it finished the first time, it takes only some seconds. Does MySQL store something like "the last x queries"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is yes. there is a Query Cache.

> The query cache stores the text of a SELECT statement together with the corresponding result that was sent to the client. If an identical statement is received later, the server retrieves the results from the query cache rather than parsing and executing the statement again. The query cache is shared among sessions, so a result set generated by one client can be sent in response to the same query issued by another client.

from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html)

Answer (score 0):

The execution plan for the query will be calculated and re-used.  The data can be cached, so subsequent executions will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, depending on how the MySQL Server is configured, it may be using the query cache. This stores the results of identical queries until a certain limit (which you can set if you control the server) has been reached. Read [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.htmlhttp://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html) to find out more about how to tune your query cache to speed up your application if it issues many identical queries.